# Why am I getting the Angular $injector:modulerr error here? Using 1.5 beta

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

The markup

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Angular I</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="author" href="humans.txt">
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

    <section ng-controller="mainCtrl">
      <h1>My App</h1>
      <p>{{name}}</p>
    </section>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The script.js

```
var app = angular.module('friendsList', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Leon Gaban";
})
```

I'm including angular.min, angular-route and even angular-resource and animate...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had wrong `ng-app` module, it should be `ng-app="friendsList"` instead of `app`.

The error is not due to angular versions, it is because you are injecting wrong dependency in your app mdoule. Simply you can not inject `mainCtrl` inside your module as its controller `mainCtrl` which you are going to register with your module.

```
var app = angular.module('friendsList', []);
```

Also you should have `ng-controller="mainCtrl"` on html.

```
<section ng-controller="mainCtrl">

</section>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah sorry that was messed up, I fixed that... however I still have the `$injector` error... I think it has something to do with my Angular lib scripts?

Comment: AH Thanks! Lol... forgot that :)

Comment: @LeonGaban Glad to help you..Thanks :)